# NTP synchronization with GPS

Tags: ubuntu, gps, ntp

I'm using ubuntu and trying to synchronizing NTP with GPS.
ppstest works fine and also gpsmon.
how can i check that the NTP is synchronized with the GPS?
are there any indications?

Comment: You are in the wrong site. Maybe SuperUser is best suited for you. in any case you should be more precise: NTP is a "protocol" to send/get time. Kernel usually keep track of time, with some correction given by a ntp deamon. log files is a good starting point.

Comment: try; `ntpq -pcrv`